# Crystal reports viewer .NET and Internet Explorer spill-over bug

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, reporting

I've a problem in reports visualization under Crystal reports viewer 13 and Internet explorer.

I explain: when I have a multi-line text field in the details section and that field contains some specific characters ('-', '(', ' ', ')'...), the viewer seems to detect the last occurrence of on of those characters in a line and cut the text there. The cut text, that remains of the line is put between it's mother line and the following line.

The problem is that this field is part of details section so there will be a vertical spillover between the lines of the report.

Any help please?

Comment: Thx! The problem is resolved by adding: CrystalReportViewer1.RenderingDPI = 120;

Answer (score 3):

The problem is resolved by adding: CrystalReportViewer1.RenderingDPI = 120;

Comment: great! solved for me! Anyway, Changing RenderingDPI increase the size of report in the page.